# hvplot widgets not working in vscode (visual studio code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, hvplot

Examples from https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Widgets.html work fine in jupyter lab but vscode only displays them and interactive widgets dont update on drop down events. How to enable this in vscode

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution at https://github.com/bokeh/jupyter_bokeh/issues/131
after installing jupyter_bokeh , ran the following code in the above link and it worked

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension(comms="vscode")

widget = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(start=0.0, end=10.0, value=2.0, step=0.1)
widget

pn.Column(widget, widget.param.value)
```

Comment: ugh, only by downgrading notebook and jupyterlab one can install jupyter_bokeh these days. so this is a tough pay just to have hvplot working in vscode. pity it's not better supported.because linting certainly works more reliable in vscode than in jlab.